# How to polarize a laser beam

Tags: optics, polarization

I'm working on an optic project that I need my laser beam to be polarized. 
Do you a simple way to polarize my laser beam?

Comment: A [polarizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer) comes to mind.

Comment: Send the laser beam through a polarizing film.  Not that polarizing films are not 100% efficient - there will be some amount of both polarizations left, depending on the efficiency of the film you buy.

Comment: I think you also can use sunglasses in order to polarize your light.

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on how you need to polarize it.

Many lasers output highly polarized light anyway. Usually this is linearly polarized. If you need linearly polarized light, you may only need to align your laser correctly. This alignment is usually this is done with an adjustable [polarization rotator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_rotator) rather than by rotating the laser.

If you need circularly or elliptically polarized light, then you usually transform linearly polarized light into circularly polarized with a quarter wave plate: one aligns the plane of polarization at 45 degrees to the ordinary / extraordinary axis and a quarter wave delay (scaling by $i$) is then imparted on one of the components of the linearly polarization relative to the other with a birefringent crystal.

Comment: Worth pointing out the reasons why lasers produce polarized light? Just for completeness of the answer...